# Azure Blob getting downloaded with 0bytes in Azure DevOps

Tags: azure-devops, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to download blob from Azure Storage using python script as below:

```
blob_service = BlockBlobService(account_name=HIVESTORAGEACCTNAME,account_key=HIVESTORAGEACCTKEY)
            print("Storage account connected")

            print('blobname : ' + STATUSDIR+'/'+RESULTBLOBNAME)
            print('localfilename : '+LOCALFILENAME)
            blob_service.get_blob_to_path(HIVESTORAGECONTNAME,STATUSDIR+'/'+RESULTBLOBNAME,LOCALFILENAME)
            print("Blob downloaded to local file : " + LOCALFILENAME)
```

Python script when executed locally fetches/downloads the file correctly.

When same code snippet is triggered from Azure DevOps (VSTS) using private agent the file gets downloaded, but with 0bytes.

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: How are you executing this code snippet in Azure DevOps?

Comment: Is there a reason you're publishing to a storage account instead of using build artifacts?

Comment: @Jayendran - I have created CI pipeline and agent is private agent. Code is checked-in to VSTS repository and after triggering CI build, script is executed on agent.

Comment: @DanielMann - Yes, as per my requirement I want to download the file on agent and perform action on it.

Comment: You can do that with build artifacts with the Publish Build Artifact task. That makes the artifacts available for down-stream processes such as releases. If you're trying to publish build artifacts so you can later release them, then that solves your problem without involving storage accounts.